# Matrix one-norm and infinity-norm

Tags: matrices, normed-spaces

Help me please to find $3\times 3$ matrices $A$ and $B$ under following conditions:
$\left \| A \right \|_{\infty }=4\left \| A \right \|_{1}, A \neq 0$
$\left \| B \right \|_{1}=4\left \| B \right \|_{\infty }, B \neq 0$.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Well, a 1-norm satisfies that $||A||_1 = \max_j \sum_{i=1}^n |a_{ij}|$. The $\infty$ norm satisfies something very similar: $||A||_{\infty} = \max_i \sum_{j=1}^n |a_{ij}|$. Can you continue from here?

Comment: @Aahz, thanks i know this formula, but i didn't find any example that satisfies the question...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not possible, because

> **Claim:**
>   For a $A$ being an $n\times n$ matrix $A$ we have
>   $$1/n\cdot \|A\|_1\le \|A\|_\infty \le n\cdot \|A\|_1$$

*Proof:*
$$
\begin{align}
\|A\|_\infty &= \max_i \sum_j |a_{ij}| \le \sum_j\sum_{i} |a_{ij}|\le \sum_j \max_{k} \sum_i|a_{ik}|=n\|A\|_1
\end{align}
$$
This shows the first inequality. The second follows by interchanging the roles of rows and columns in this calculation. $\square$